# an issue with openfile function in python

Tags: python

I wrote a function to open a txt file and returns me three numpy array. However, I get this error all the time, which I do not have any idea why?

```
TypeError: load_data_from_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'filename'
```

here is my code:

```
def load_data_from_file(self, filename):
    # logging.info("Entered load_data_from_file")
    with open(filename, 'r') as data_file:
        wavelengths = []
        spectra = []
        delays = []
        for num, line in enumerate(data_file):
            if num == 0:
                # Get the 1st line, drop the 1st element, and convert it
                # to a float array.
                delays = array([float(stri) for stri in line.split()[1:]])
            else:
                data = [float(stri) for stri in line.split()]
                # The first column contains wavelengths.
                wavelengths.append(data[0])
                # All other columns contain intensity at that wavelength
                # vs time.
                spectra.append(array(data[1:]))
    logging.info("Data loaded from file has sizes (%dx%d)" % (delays.size, len(wavelengths)))
    return delays, array(wavelengths), vstack(spectra).Tenter code here
```

I appriciate any comments on this.

Comment: Is `load_data_from_file` a method in a class? If that's the case, you have to call it using `x.load_data_from_file(filename)` where `x` is an instance of such class. If this is not a class method, remove the `self` argument.

Comment: @aaossa you are right, it was a method in a class. thanks

Comment: Added my comment as an answer in case you consider that it solves your problem. Let me know if you have any questions about it

Comment: What about the identation, the whole structure under the def must be moved right ... ?

Comment: @pedram I'm not sure why you marked another answer as the accepted answer when it does not address your actual issue. You said in the comments that your function was actually a class method, and the accepted answer assumes it is not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are referring is when you call the function `load_data_from_file()`.It seems that you are not passing the filename correctly in the parameters. The correct way to call it should be something like:

```
output = load_data_from_file("myfile.txt")
```

Also, I'm not sure, but if you are passing parameter `self` should indicate that you are using class?
Please upload your full code here so we can have a better understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

According to the question comments, the problem seems to be that this is actually a class method (a function defined inside a class). Because of this, you have to use your function as a method of a class instance:

```
my_instance = YourClass(...)
my_instance.load_data_from_file(filename)
```

This way, your `self` and `filename` arguments are correctly used.